# Using Ember.js Models with asynchronous jQuery Ajax callbacks

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, ember.js, couchdb, ember-router

I'm currently building my first Ember.js app. My problem is to return the response of a jQuery Ajax similar call (asynchronous) to `App.PostRoute`'s `model` property. I'm a bit confused that the `IndexRoute` works and the `PostRoute` does not. `couchdb.read(doc, callback)` returns an single object to the callback and `couchdb.view(doc, func, callback)` returns an array of objects to the callback. My main source for this Ember.js app was [twbrandt.github.com/2013/02/11/Ember-Quick_Start_Guide](http://twbrandt.github.com/2013/02/11/Ember-Quick_Start_Guide/).

```
    this.App = Ember.Application.create();

    App.Router.map(function () {
        this.resource('post', { path: '/posts/:post_id' });
    });
    App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function() {
            return App.Post.newest();
        }
    });
    App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function (parameters) {
            return App.Post.get(parameters.post_id);
        }
    });
    App.Post = Ember.Object.extend();
    App.Post.reopenClass({
        get: function (id) {
            var post;
            couchdb.read('post-' + id, function (response) {
                post = App.Post.create(response); // thanks to mavilein
            }); // gets a single post by it's id
            return post;
        },
        newest: function () {
            var posts = [];
            couchdb.view('posts', 'all?limit=10&descending=true', function (posts) {
                posts.forEach(function (post) {
                    posts.addObject(App.Post.create(post));
                }, this);
            }); // loads the 10 newest posts
            return posts;
        }
    });
```

**Update:** Thanks to [mavilein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1073635/mavilein) for his help, now it works better! But I just have the problem that I can't directly access single-post pages (it only shows the default template). I always have to visit the index page first and then click on a link to a single-post page. Here's a jsFiddle that contains my whole code. [jsfiddle.net/dZs2X/2](http://jsfiddle.net/dZs2X/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to create a Post Object in your get function (there is no App.Post.create there).

Try this:

```
 post = App.Post.create(response);
```

PS: sorry for bad formatting but i am on smartphone right now :-)

Comment: Thank's for your help, now it works better but not perfect yet. :) I've created a jsFiddle with my HTML too, mabe the error is somewhere else. http://jsfiddle.net/dZs2X/2/